# Create a new array using child array, but include parent array information

Tags: angular

I have the following JSON array:

```
var results= "[{
            "name": "Duncan",
            "age": 23,
            "children": [{
                    "nickname": "John"
                },
                {
                    "nickname": "Susan"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Mike",
            "age": 30,
            "children": [{
                "nickname": "Don"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "Chad",
            "age": 40,
            "children": []
        }
    ]"
```

I would like to create an array from the above, such that it looks like this:

```
[{
        "nickname": "John",
        "age": 23,
        "name": "Duncan"
    },
    {
        "nickname": "Susan",
        "age": 23,
        "name": "Duncan"
    },
    {
        "nickname": "Don",
        "age": 30,
        "name": "Mike"
    }
]
```

In my example, since chad had no children, that entry should be ignored.

I have tried to do this, but it didn't work.

```
allChildren: any[] = [];

for (let i=0;i<this.results.length;i++)
  {
    if(this.results[i].children.length > 0)
    {
    this.allChildren = [...this.allChildren, ...this.results[i].children]
    this.allChildren[i]["name"] = this.results[i].name
    this.allChildren[i]["age"] = this.results[i].age
    }
  }
 console.log(this.allChildren)
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would use reduce for this as it's really a list flattening operation with a transform, and not a simple transform:

```
allChildren = results.reduce((acc, val) => {
  return acc.concat(val.children.map(child => ({nickname: child.nickname, name: val.name, age: val.age})));
}, []);
```

1. start with an empty array
2. iterate over results values
3. for each value, map the children into an array of your desired values
4. then concat the mapped children array to your previous accumulated values

this naturally 'ignores' items without any children, as you'd just be concating to an empty array. you'll probably want to get trickier in your child transform if the objects are more complicated than your example.